# How should I return an error (and a message) in large project?

Tags: php, return

I'm writing a large project, and here's a class that I'll use it often:

```
class Star
{
    /**
     * Add
     *
     * Add a star to something.
     *
     * @param int $ID   The ID of the thing.
     */

    function Add($ID)
    {
        if($this->Starred($ID))
            return 'You starred it already.';

        if(!$this->Existing($ID))
            return 'The one you tried to star does no longer exist.';

        $this->DB->Star($ID);

        return 'Starred successfully!';
    }
}

$Star = new Star();
```

But I will use it in different ways like: **single page** or **inside a function**,

here's the problem, **sometimes, I want to know the return code not the message**,

but when I use it in the single page, I want it to return the messaage,

so if I change the `Add()` function to this:

```
function Add($ID)
{
    if($this->Starred($ID))
        return 0;

    if(!$this->Existing($ID))
        return 1;

    $this->DB->Star($ID);

    return 2;
}
```

I can now use it in my functions like this to handle an error:

```
/** Leaves a comment */
$Comment->Say('Hello.', $ID);

/** Auto star the post because we commented on it */
if($Star->Add($ID) == 2)
{
    /** Remove the comment because the post does no longer exist */
    $Comment->Remove('Hello.', $ID);

    return 'Sorry ; _ ;, the post does no longer exist.';
}
```

but what if I need to return a message in many other pages?

I need to write this code every time?

```
switch($Star->Add($ID))
{
    case 0:
        return 'You starred it already.';
        break;

    case 1:
        return 'The one you tried to star does no longer exist.';
        break;

    case 2:
        return 'Starred successfully!';
        break;
}
```

I'm just confuse about it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add two more functions `getCode()` and `getMessage()`. Assign the code and message to private variables. Make `getCode()` return the code and the same with message.

Comment: You could return an object or array with properties like ['message'] and ['code'].  In the case of an array, your other functions could use functions like [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) or [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to manipulate the results and access $response['message'] or $response['code']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*For a direct solution to your code read the* **Edit 1** *section*.

I'm currently working on a rather large project and I'm using a `ErrorHandler` class that I made. I found that working with a generic error handler class has made it easier.

```
class ErrorHandler
{
    /**
     * @var string an array containing all the errors set.
     */
    private static $errors = [];

    /**
     * Set an error.
     * 
     * @param string $error - The error message you'd like to set.
     * @return string - The error being set to $errors array.
     */
    public static function add($error)
    {
        return self::$errors[] = $error;
    }

    /**
     * Get all the errors.
     * 
     * @return boolean if the $errors array is empty it will return false, otherwise it will return the errors.
     */
    public static function get()
    {
        foreach (self::$errors as $error) {
            if (empty(trim($error)))
                return false;
        }
        return self::$errors;
    }
}
```

Basically how I use it is like this, say I needed to validate a form input say a login, I'd first check if the user pressed the submit button, then I'd use the `ternary operator` to run some validations and if it fails I use the `ErrorHandler` class.

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $emailAddress = someValidationsHere ? doSomethingWithValidInput : ErrorHandler::add("Email field is empty or format is invalid.");
    $password = someValidationsHere ? doSomethingWithValidInput : ErrorHandler::add("Password field can't be empty and can't use special characters.");

    if(!ErrorHandler::get()) {                    
        echo User::login($emailAddress, $password, $autoLogin);
    } else {
        $errors = ErrorHandler::get();

        foreach($errors as $error) {
            echo $error . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

So what that bottom `if statement` does is check if the `ErrorHandler::get` functions does **not** return `false` which in that case no need to show an error message and you can progress with the code, `else` it will display the error page, this way you can show multiple errors and have custom formatting.

I prefer this method as it is more of a long term solution as you may change the ID's then you'd have to go through all your code and change the code manually. Also it gives your code some sort of structure and that keeps your code clean.

**Edit 1**

How is this class? You now know the error codes using the `const` value and you can `parse` the error code to a message using the `getMessage` function. Also your code is more understandable and adaptable.

*Why is it more...*

*understandable?*

**Because now when you (or someone else) looks at this code they see the clean name from the `const` so `ALREADY_STARRED_ERROR` will let the developer know instantly what the error means.**

*adaptable?*

**Well now you can change your hard coded errors and it wouldn't affect the code in anyway, so if in the future you wish to changed it because of a spelling mistake or other errors, you can change the array message.**

```
<?php
class Star
{
    const ALREADY_STARRED_ERROR = 1;
    const NOT_FOUND_ERROR= 2;
    const SUCCESSFUL_ENTRY = 3;
    
    function getMessage($code)
    {
        $messages = [
            1 => "You starred it already.",
            2 => "The one you tried to star does no longer exist.",
            3 => "Starred successfully!"
        ];
        
        return $message[$code];
    }
    
    /**
     * Add
     *
     * Add a star to something.
     *
     * @param int $ID   The ID of the thing.
     */

    function Add($ID)
    {
        if($this->Starred($ID))
            return self::ALREADY_STARRED_ERROR;

        if(!$this->Existing($ID))
            return self::NOT_FOUND_ERROR;

        $this->DB->Star($ID);

        return self::SUCCESSFUL_ENTRY;
    }
}
?>
```

I'd like to think **Edit 1** addressed both the issues you had.

> sometimes, I want to know the return code not the message,
>
> but when I use it in the single page, I want it to return the messaage,

Comment: I'll try your ErrorHandler class later, but how does the `Edit 1` return the status codes? It seems only returns the message. And I edited my question, it's now return a json not only a single string.

Comment: @YamiOdymel The status code is held in the `const` value, so you'd `echo` that. Then to get the message you'd echo `getMessage(constOverHere)`. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: How do I get the status code if I executed `$Star->Add()` ?

Answer (score 2):

Place the switch to a function, like `AddWithMessage`:

```
function AddWithMessage($Star)
{
  switch($Star->Add($ID))
  {
    case 0:
        return 'You starred it already.';
        break;

    case 1:
        return 'The one you tried to star does no longer exist.';
        break;

    case 2:
        return 'Starred successfully!';
        break;
  }
}
```

Then use it across any single page you need instead of `Add`